# Has my macOS Sierra system been infected by unknown users?

Tags: macos, mac, malware, macos-sierra

I noticed my system was running slow today and checked the list of system users in Terminal as a precaution. I found several users that I don’t recognize. Should I be concerned?

```
_applepay
_captiveagent
_ctkd
_datadetectors
_findmydevice
_gamecontrollerd
_hidd
_mbsetupuser
_mobileasset
_ondemand
_pcastagent
_pcastlibrary
_pcastserver
_wwwproxy
_xgridagent
_xgridcontroller
_xserverdocs
```

Answer (score 30):

Apple's macOS has a number of built-in user accounts, with many of the system services running under dedicated user accounts. These special user accounts are prefixed with an underscore (`_`).

For example, `_applepay` is used for the Apple Pay daemon, and `_findmydevice` for the Find My Mac feature.

While these users are "users" to the system, they are special background users modern Unix-like systems use to keep processes contained and more-secure, and not quite the same as the user accounts you might login to your computer as.

Having a number of these pseudo-users is normal, and not itself a sign your system is compromised.

Answer (score 10):

These “users” are not actual users—as in human users who are logged in—but rather they are called “[daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing))” users (aka: “service” accounts) created by the OS to manage processes and such in the background as part of normal OS operation. This is not idiosyncratic to macOS but rather a common practice of most any modern operating system (and perhaps a few older, not-so-modern operating systems).

You can see the full list of users on any macOS system by running this command in the Terminal:

```
dscl . -list /Users
```

On my macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) install, I see this is output from that command:

```
_amavisd
_appleevents
_applepay
_appowner
_appserver
_ard
_assetcache
_astris
_atsserver
_avbdeviced
_calendar
_captiveagent
_ces
_clamav
_coreaudiod
_coremediaiod
_ctkd
_cvmsroot
_cvs
_cyrus
_datadetectors
_devdocs
_devicemgr
_displaypolicyd
_distnote
_dovecot
_dovenull
_dpaudio
_eppc
_findmydevice
_ftp
_gamecontrollerd
_geod
_hidd
_iconservices
_installassistant
_installer
_jabber
_kadmin_admin
_kadmin_changepw
_krb_anonymous
_krb_changepw
_krb_kadmin
_krb_kerberos
_krb_krbtgt
_krbfast
_krbtgt
_launchservicesd
_lda
_locationd
_lp
_mailman
_mbsetupuser
_mcxalr
_mdnsresponder
_mobileasset
_mysql
_netbios
_netstatistics
_networkd
_nsurlsessiond
_nsurlstoraged
_ondemand
_postfix
_postgres
_qtss
_sandbox
_screensaver
_scsd
_securityagent
_serialnumberd
_softwareupdate
_spotlight
_sshd
_svn
_taskgated
_teamsserver
_timezone
_tokend
_trustevaluationagent
_unknown
_update_sharing
_usbmuxd
_uucp
_warmd
_webauthserver
_windowserver
_www
_wwwproxy
_xcsbuildagent
_xcscredserver
_xserverdocs
daemon
jake
nobody
root
```